# How can I restart Windows 7 and have it reopen all files, email and browsers that were open?

Tags: windows-7

When Windows update finishes installing critical updates, it frequently forces a restart.  When the system triggers a forced restart, the session comes back with everything open as it was.  This includes all open files (regardless of program - Word, Excel, QuickBooks, Notepad, etc.), all emails that were open during an MS Outlook session, and all browser tabs (IE, Chrome, etc.).

I frequently have 50 or more instances of something open while working and prefer not to reboot any more often than necessary, due to the effort required to close out, remember and reopen the particular files/tabs/emails.  However, thanks to good old MS memory management, occasionally a reboot is necessary due to drivers stopping or browsers hogging memory.

Because Windows 7 can be rebooted and reopen a complete session and all files, etc. when necessary after a Windows Update, how can I do that during one of my reboots?

Comment: This would require third-party software.  What software that stores desktop sessions have you tried but ruled out?

Comment: True, I've seen the comments about doing this with 3rd party software.  However, I know Windows 7 can already do this, because it does this during windows update forced reboots.  So, I would just like to know how to access "reboot and restore session" feature/switch/setting within Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting reboot, select the `hibernate` option. This will save the state of all your open programs in your storage device. When you start the PC again, it should load all the programs that were open before the PC was put in hibernate mode.

You might have to configure your browsers to reopen tabs when the browser starts since that is not the default behavior for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact problem too. It's so frustrating how there's no good answer out there. Spent quite some time searching the whole internet and stumbled upon one.
The software is called [Instant File Opener](https://www.magnonic.com/ifo.shtml). It works on Windows 10 as of May 31, 2020. You may have to run compatibility troubleshooter if it happened to crash.

For browsers like Chrome, I've been using an extension called [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en). It's awesome.

For windows explorer, there are [Q-Dir](http://www.q-dir.com/) and [One Commander](http://onecommander.com/) that let you open multiple tabs of explorers in a single window. I prefer Q-Dir. You can open 4 windows at the same time and you can also add tabs to each window. You can save sessions too. I normally add shortcuts to Start Menu where files are indexed. To open, you just hit <kbd>Win</kbd> and type.

[image: Q-Dir]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you use a browser like Chrome, it will detect this and re-open your browser tabs if you choose so. MS Office documents can be recovered as well. With other software, this is a bit of an issue though... You could write a little script that runs in the background that checks running processes and open files and writes any changes to disk. Based on that, it could re-open the docs and software.
However, you could also set your Windows Updates to notify you and not install automatically. This way, you don't experience sudden downtime BUT you have to be disciplined enough to manually update regularly when you can spare a few minutes. The problem with that is that most people just ignore and remain with an unsafe system.

If you're talking about your own computer, I would choose the Windows Updates setting. If you're on a work computer, maybe an admin can help you with that script.